# why does this not work if the page is already slightly scrolled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this effect that makes the header change from fixed to absolute and scroll with the rest of the page when a target div hits it.

The problem is that if the page is slightly scrolled on load then it breaks the calculations that tell the header where to sit on the page is wrong and it ruins the effect. I cant work out the issue.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
            targetTopPos = targetEl.offsetTop + 100;
            console.log(targetTopPos);
        };
        
        const headerEl = document.querySelector('header')
        const targetEl = document.querySelector('#target')
        
        let targetTopPos = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top

        let isHeaderFixed = true

        document.onscroll = () => {
            let targetTopOffset = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top
            console.log(targetTopOffset);
            
            if (isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset < 100) {
                headerEl.style.position = 'absolute'
                headerEl.style.top = `${targetTopPos - 100}px`
                isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
            }
            
            if (!isHeaderFixed && targetTopOffset >= 100) {
                headerEl.style.position = 'fixed'
                headerEl.style.top = '0px'
                isHeaderFixed = !isHeaderFixed
            }
        }
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.content {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.target {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Custom header
</header>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
<div id="target" class="target">target</div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam suscipit tellus urna, ut tristique felis lobortis sed. Phasellus maximus at magna mattis vulputate. Pellentesque tempor, urna vitae congue pellentesque, est mauris faucibus nulla, vitae molestie leo purus a leo. Curabitur ut mi ac sem finibus consectetur a blandit massa. Morbi ornare tincidunt ipsum, et accumsan erat fringilla a. Cras egestas, nibh vel condimentum ultrices, nunc ipsum tempus magna, eu ullamcorper tortor magna id lacus. Morbi euismod lacus a ligula rutrum, in aliquet lectus blandit. Nam placerat sollicitudin lectus eu ornare. Etiam placerat diam eget magna blandit rutrum. Nulla et luctus massa. Sed sit amet mauris in magna tincidunt consequat. Proin mattis sit amet arcu a gravida. Nullam tempor urna nec dolor convallis consectetur sit amet a elit. Cras ut odio nec lacus efficitur porta nec sit amet justo.
</div>
```

For some reason that code doesn't work exactly as it does on my real site, on the real site you can resize, if you are scrolled to the top, and the effect still works.

Comment: can you share your working example?

Comment: the code is litterally the same i dont know what the problem is the fix it. The js at least is identical

Answer (score 0):

You can try this js if you want with the styles. This js adds a class to your header when it reaches a specific height of scroll.

```
<!--JS-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
                function myFunction() {
                    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
                        document.getElementById("myheader").className = "sticky";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("myheader").className = "";
            }
        }
</script>


<!--HTML-->
<div id="myheader">
    //logo and nav
</div>


<!--CSS-->
#myheader{
    position: relative;
}
#myheader.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Hi this isn't anything to do with the code i have or the effect i have